# github : push permission denied (

Tags: github, push, ssh-keys

I know the question has been asked several times.
From my local machine I try to upload files to my repository:

```
:~/Git-JeanPat/pyFISH$ git push -u origin master
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

my repository is

```
https://github.com/jeanpat/pyFISH
```

I check my password from the admin interface of github.

I made a new  ssh key from command line, and I copy it on github.
When I check my connection as [indicated](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey). it fails:

```
~/Git-JeanPat/pyFISH$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/simon/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/simon/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/simon/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/simon/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/simon/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/simon/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/simon/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/simon/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve jeanpat    95:e1:bb:60:b5:31:63:39:3a:99:d1:01:22:87:3c:15
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/simon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/simon/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I reboot my ubuntu 12.04 laptop and everything went fine ...